# WPF binding to nested objects in a ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, binding, resourcedictionary

I have an object tree which is included in a ResourceDictionary in my application.  The root node of this object tree has an x:Key associated with it. I want to bind a control to a property of one of the nested items in this tree. How can I get access to a child element of a keyed ResourceDictionary to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<MyControl
   MyProperty="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyResourceKey}, Path=ChildProperty.Children[1].AndSoOn}"/>
```

Comment: Not quite the solution to my problem but I guess that was my fault for my poorly worded question as opposed to your solution which does exactly what I asked! Thanks.